# Time Checking in PHP

Tags: php

To start off I'm sorry for the noob question. Learning as I go but I'm having issues with this and couldn't fine the right search.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- I'm currently trying to combine strings of text and numbers for a ban list.

For example a person is banned for 40 minutes, In the SQL database it is stored as the value 40.That is fine when displayed in a table however issues arise when a person is banned for 10080 minutes (1 week)

What I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, authid, name, length FROM sb_ctbans";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     if ($row["length"]  < '60'){
          $row["length"] . "Minutes"  == $ban['length'];
          echo $ban['length'];
        } else {
            $row["length"] . "Undefined length" ==   $ban['length'];
    }
        echo "<tr>"."<td>" . $row["name"] ."</td>" . "<td>" . $row["authid"] ."</td>" . "<td>" . $ban['length'] . "</td>"   ."</tr>";
    }
```

Expected output: 2 Minutes
Actual output:

Cheers for any help.

---

Edit: 
After changing from:
`$row["length"] . "Minutes"  == $ban['length'];`

To:

```
      `        $ban['length'] = $row.['length'] . 'Minutes';`
```

I am now reviving the output `ArrayArray Minutes`

Comment: No output is being displayed.

Comment: what is your intended logic with this line? `$row["length"] . "Minutes"  == $ban['length'];` or is that a typo of some sort, and where is `$ban` defined

Comment: Hi, The intended result is if $row["length"] = less than 60 that in will used the period to add "Minutes" to the string and than make the result $ban['length'];

Comment: @NickCotter then that assignment is incorrect, its `$ban['length'] = ... code after`

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte Cheers for the response, after changing to  `      $ban['length'] = $row.['lenth'] . 'Minutes'; ` My output is now ArrayArray Minutes.

Comment: Storing the number of minutes is... uncommon. Either store seconds and work with UNIX timestamp logic, or store actual *timestamps* (e.g. `banned_until` as a `DATETIME` column).

Comment: try something like this   $ban['length'] = $row['length'] . 'Minutes';   remove the dot after $row.['length']

Comment: @deceze, I agree. You should have a table that defines a type of ban and contain it's ban length, then you store the unix timestamp of when the ban occurs and mathematically work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.  You fixed the first wrong line, but it's again wrong at `$row["length"] . "Undefined length" ==   $ban['length'];`.  Also, you're checking if the $row['length'] is less than the STRING '60', not the number 60, which could be causing errors.  Finally, as others have said, storing the number of minutes to ban is sure to cause problems eventually.  Instead, when the ban is first established, calculate the time it will be when the ban expires and store that instead.  When you check it, calculate how long til the time you stored.  Otherwise as time passes, you must update every ban record every minute or they become inaccurate.